# complex numbers equality question

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a$ be given a complex number. Show that

$$\left|\frac{z-a}{1-a^*z}\right|=1$$

for $z$ with $|z|=1$ and $a^*z\neq 1$.

If $|z|=1$, that means $z$ can be equal to $i$, $-i$, $1$ or $-1$ right?
Also I tried multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate of the bottom but it didn't really help.

Comment: $|z| = 1$ means that $z$ is a point on the unit circle. There are more than four of those. First use the fact that $|v/w| = |v|/|w|$. That will clarify what you need to prove a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to show

$$\left|\frac{z-a}{1-a^*z}\right|^2=1$$

But

$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{z-a}{1-a^*z}\right|^2&=\frac{z-a}{1-a^*z}\frac{z^*-a^*}{1-az^*}\\&=\frac{zz^*+aa^*-az^*-a^*z}{1+aa^*zz^*-az^*-a^*z}\\&=\frac{zz^*+aa^*-az^*-a^*z}{zz^*+aa^*-az^*-a^*z}\ \ \ \ \text{using that }zz^*=|z|^2=1\\&=1\end{align}$$

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to write
$$\dfrac{1+aa^*-az^*-a^*z}{1+aa^*-az^*-a^*z}$$

Comment: @Demosthene If $1=1$ it makes *as much* sense to write $1$ as to write $1$. Does it make sense?

Comment: I mean, you say you're using the condition $zz^*=1$, which allows you to write $aa^*zz^*=aa^*$. The $1$ is already there in the denominator. So why not simply apply the same rule to the numerator, and write $zz^*+aa^*+\ldots=1+aa^*+\ldots$?

Comment: @Demosthene Because people who have a weak preparation in mathematics don't realize that an equation $a=b$ can serve both to replace $a$ for $b$ as to replace $b$ for $a$. They need to be shown that.

Comment: wait so $|z-a|^2=(z-a)^2=(z-a)(z^*-a^*)$?

Comment: @snowman No, only $|z-a|^2=(z-a)(z^*-a^*)$.

Comment: I'm starting to find your comments borderline insulting. But anyway. Of course an equation can work both ways. But in this particular case, you're using a property to make a transformation that is not needed. I'm sorry, even though everything reduces to $1=1$, you're not being consistent. There are two possibilities: either rewrite the $1$ in the denominator and the $aa^*$ in the numerator as $zz^*$ and $aa^*zz^*$, or replace all $zz^*$ by $1$. The latter is more elegant in my opinion, and your way of doing it is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Demosthene They are intended to be insulting. I was just hoping you realize by yourself that your question is stupid. You are even saying that one transformation that requires two changes in two places, is better than another transformation that makes two changes, in two places, the sizes of which, and the nature of which are all the same. Tell, me. Still don't get it?

Comment: Excuse me, but you're actually making two transformations, $zz^*\to 1$ and $1\to zz^*$. I'm just saying, for the sake of simplicity, why not simply make the unique transformation $zz^*\to 1$? They amount to the same, but one might be less confusing or simpler looking or whatever you want to call it. Ockham's razor.

Comment: @Demosthene Oh God! And you are making two transformations $zz^*\to 1$ and $zz^*\to1$ one in the numerator, one in the denominator. Mine are both in the denominator. Which is better? $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, "Let $m$ be a prime number" or "Let $p$ be a prime number". Ockham's razor has nothing to do with this, the assumptions are the same even the size of the procedures are the same. But don't worry. Stick there strongly to your irrelevant opinion. Good luck doing math. LOL.

Comment: Can you argue that $zz^*$ is a visually simpler expression of the unit than $1$ itself?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\displaystyle \left| \frac{z-a}{1-a^{*}z} \right| = \frac{|z-a|}{|1-a^{*}z|}$, it's enough to show that $|z-a| = |1 - a^{*}z|$. Because $|z| = 1$, we have $zz^{*} = |z|^2 = 1$ and also $|z^{*}| = |z| = 1$. Hence
$$|1 - a^{*}z| = |1 - a^{*}z||z^{*}| = |(1 - a^{*}z)z^{*}| = |z^{*} - a^{*}zz^{*}| = |z^{*} - a^{*}| = |(z - a)^{*}| = |z-a|.$$